# How to merge all layers in QGIS project using 'merge vector layers' within PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, vector, merge

I am trying to use the 'merge vector layers' tool in PyQGIS to merge all of the layers in my QGIS project into one shapefile, as part of a larger script I am developing. I tried this script, but I get an error related to the input layers. I am using QGIS 3.0.0.

```
processing.algorithmHelp('native:mergevectorlayers')
input = iface.mapCanvas().layers()  
processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers',{'LAYERS':input,'CRS':4326,'OUTPUT':'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\COOPI\GIS_Data\CWW_Predictive_Targeting\GEOREF_HH_GPS_Data\Shapefiles\Merged\TA_Mponda_GVH_Bolera_malunga.shp'})
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 64, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: use double slash in yout paths

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting an error when I use the double slashes..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 84, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 190, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.

Comment: It worked with single forward slashes / in the file paths

Comment: @J Clifford, please provide that finding as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code works when using a single forward slash (/) in the file paths

Comment: Alternatively, someone can add a `r` in front of the file path string (just before the first quote `'`) and continue using forward slash. It's called a raw string.